# Server stops responding after connecting from client to spigot server (minecraft server)

Tags: server, java, 18.10, openjdk, minecraft

I recently started new mc server spigot with plugins. It worked fine. But after 100+ connections, 10 multiverse (plugin) worlds, and milion blocks i restarted the server. All was fine, spigot console commands worked (from SSH) but when i connect to server from pc, server immediantly stoped responding, from virtual box (not via SSH) console and i wasnt able to write something or just log in. After ubuntu server 18.10 restart from virtual box server was responding. But when i ran the spigot server from byobu, and connect from pc, ubuntu stopped responding and i haved to restart server again.

Sorry for bad english :v

(Using ubuntu server 4GB ram, 4 cores ver. 18.10, java: openjdk-8-jdk (package name))

Comment: could you post the relevant logfiles? namely the spigot log files and maybe the connecting client's logfiles

Comment: @Zalgo this is my log: https://pastebin.com/KLftXcnJ it looks normal. After connecting, it just stopped writing log, and stopped responding. On client, after I tried to connect, Mc just showed me dirtblock background and Java error: "The connection was terminated by the remote host"